# Oracle APEX Liquibase Environment Data Changesets

Tags: oracle-apex, liquibase, sqlcl

We are in the process of trying to integrate sqlcl liquibase into our Oracle APEX deployment process. The one hiccup we came across is when we need to migrate data. Specifically, we have a table that holds data based on the environment (DEV, UAT, PRD) that you are in. So data will not be the same across these environments. Ideally we would love to include this in the automated process as this data gets updated. Anyone doing something similar and have a solution to share? FYI, I am using Oracle's sqlcl liquibase version.

Not ideal, but for now we would plan to do manually with an environment_data script that would be run manually in each database environment.

UPDATE w/ table definition:

```sql
ENVRONMENT_VARIABLES
=============================
variable_key    varchar2(50)
variable_value  varchar2(500)

(DEV data)
variable_key         variable_value
---------------------------------------
env_label            DEV
process_start_date   01/01/2023
image_server         http://dev_server:8080


(UAT data)
variable_key         variable_value
---------------------------------------
env_label            UAT
process_start_date   01/01/2023
image_server         http://uat_server:8085


(PRD data)
variable_key         variable_value
---------------------------------------
env_label            PRD
process_start_date   01/01/2023
image_server         http://prd_server:8085
```

Comment: how much data? like how many rows are we talking about? there are a couple of different ways you could do this and performance/speed is probably a concern, yes?

Comment: Currently only 4 or 5 records. I'm sure it will grow a bit more, but do not foresee more than 50 rows. So it is basically a small lookup/reference table.

Comment: then the standard data changeSets will work just fine, but if you had 4,000 or 40,000, or 400,000 inserts, we can batch insert those with SQLcl script changeSets

Comment: so would I just create a changeset and then manually update the data before running the update statement? is there a link with examples for me to reference somewhere?